# Multiple Date Range in a query

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, range

I have few tables from where i want to create a query with multiple date range column. Here is an example:

```
          |  Date Range_1 |  Date Range_2 |
          |   01-31 Jan   |   01-30 Feb   |

          ---- col1,col2 -----col3, col4 ----



SELECT temp_a.*
FROM (SELECT col_1,col_2, col_3 from xyz WHERE (date BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-01-30')
AND id = 70
GROUP BY a1 a2) temp_a
INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON a.id = t1.id



SELECT temp_b.*
FROM (SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3 from xyz WHERE (date BETWEEN '2011-02-01' AND '2011-02-30')
AND id = 70
GROUP BY a1 a2) temp_b
INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON b.id = t1.id

 I need all the column from temp_a and temp_b like this

 |temp_a.col_1 | temp_a.col_2 | temp_a.col_3 | temp_b.col_1 | temp_b.col_2 | temp_b.col_3 |
```

the above two query can return two different range value but i want to get the ranged values in a single query.

Please help.

thanks in advance.

- Shahidul, Dhaka, Bangladesh.

Answer (score 5):

Use `OR` in the `WHERE` clause.

```
WHERE ((date BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-01-30')
       OR (date BETWEEN '2011-02-01' AND '2011-02-30'))
```

Comment: I need data from both the table ( I want to join both the query any how)

Comment: You already have the join. Just replace your WHERE clause with mine.